# Highlighting second set of latex command in a listing

Tags: listings

I'm trying to get a second set of (own defined) Latex commands to get highlighted with the `listings` package, but I don't succeed. See the MWE below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[AlLaTeX]TeX,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        moretexcs={resizebox},
        texcsstyle=*\color{blue}\slshape,
        texcs=[2]{thesiscolor,thesisauthor}
%       texcsstyle=[2]{*\color{red}},
%       texcsstyle=[2]*\color{red},
%       texcsstyle=[2]\color{red}\sffamily,
        texcsstyle={*[2]\color{red}\sffamily},
}

\begin{document}

Lorum ...

\begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\resizebox{..}{..}{..}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
\thesiscolor{..}
\thesisauthor{...}
\end{lstlisting}

Lorum ...

\end{document}
```

If I understand the documentation correctly, I should use something like `texcsstyle=[2]*\color{red}` but it doesn't work (nor do variations on this subject). So how to get the second set of command to get highlighted in red?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a comma missing

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[AlLaTeX]TeX,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        moretexcs={resizebox},
        texcsstyle=*\color{blue}\slshape,
        texcs=[2]{thesiscolor,thesisauthor}, %<-------
        texcsstyle=[2]\color{red}\sffamily,
}

\begin{document}

Lorum ...

\begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\resizebox{..}{..}{..}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
\thesiscolor{..}
\thesisauthor{...}
\end{lstlisting}

Lorum ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ohhhhh really!!!! Ouch! Ok, this question is due for deletion...